# Fazer o Bootstrap 4 usar 100% da altura da tela

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Sempre que crio uma row no, é pego o tamanho de acordo com a quantidade de elemento, ai quero centralizar o card e não consigo, pois não pega 100% da tela

```
<div class="container h-100">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-4 my-auto">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <img src="http://s1134.photobucket.com/user/PW_PrimeiroChefe/media/Kratos.png.html" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" alt="Logo da Empresa">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Login</h5>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle">nome da empresa</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Usuário</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Senha</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Entrar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Veja a centralização do card em: https://jsfiddle.net/maujor/93wdqtz6/15/ **Edição aqui:** Para centralizar o card defina para a row uma altura igual a 100vh.

Answer (score 2):

Ajuste o `html, body` no CSS para ter a altura do *viewport*:

```
html, body{
   height: 100%;
}
```

Em seguida coloque a class `h-100` também na `.row`:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center h-100">
```

**Exemplo:**

```css
html, body{
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container h-100">
<div class="row justify-content-center h-100">
    <div class="col-4 my-auto">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <img src="http://s1134.photobucket.com/user/PW_PrimeiroChefe/media/Kratos.png.html" style="height: 30px; width: 30px;" alt="Logo da Empresa">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Login</h5>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle">nome da empresa</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Usuário</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Senha</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Entrar</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado cara, eu até tinha tentado isso, mas acontecia o seguinte, pelo fato de eu estar usando Angular 5.x.x, eu estava atribuindo o tamanho do body no css do component e não do app-root. Mas de qualquer modo, tua resposta me fez abrir os olhos. Vlw ;)